# Геокодер Yandex, ошибка scripterror

Tags: yandex-maps-api

подключаю файл с адресами, начинаю геокодировать, и практически сразу начинают валиться ошибки.

Это обработчик ошибок в коде:

> error {message: "scriptError"}

и в консоли

> GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_154296958569976489329&text=%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AB%20%D0%93.%20%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AB%2C%20%D0%A3%D0%9B.%D0%A4%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%20%D0%94.100-%D0%93%2C%D0%91%D0%98%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%A1%20%D0%A6%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%A2%D0%A0%20PRIME&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=6436365a55347e0aafee2363594c7166&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder

Несколько адресов (всегда по-разному) успевают геокодироваться.
Дело точно не в адресах ибо ранее они геокодировались отлично. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Добавьте ключ https://developer.tech.yandex.ru

Comment: Ключ получил, прописал. Не очень помогло. Все равно ошибки сыпятся. https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_154303589682966913047&text=%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AB%20%D0%93.%20%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AB%2C%20%D0%A3%D0%9B.%D0%A4%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%20%D0%94.240%D0%91&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=cb99c44a887229985617ca026781810c&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&apikey=8a9dbe38-6ed9-4c95-a5a9-2841c194505a

Comment: Вы всё ещё ловите ошибку по ключу? Если да, то нужно написать в саппорт, указав ключ и страницу, где воспроизводится проблема.

Comment: Все еще ловлю ошибку.

Comment: Продолжение вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912017/timeoutexceeded-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Со стороны Яндекса есть лимит на количество тарифицируемых запросов в секунду. При массе последовательных запросов, превышающих эти лимиты, часть запросов будет падать с ошибками. Стоит либо ограничить число таких запросов, либо организовать отправку запросов последовательно с разумной задержкой.

Замечу, что реальных кейсов, требующих отображать на публичной карте метки в значительном количестве по исходному списку адресов - единицы. А сохранение подобных данных нарушает [пользовательское соглашение](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) Яндекса и требует приобретения [расширенной коммерческой лицензии](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__tariff-plus).