# timeoutExceeded при геокодировании большого количества адресов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть необходимость геокодировать большое количество адресов (>3000).После 500-600 адресов начинает валиться сообщение "timeoutExceeded".
Входной массив адресов разбиваю на мелкие куски и скармливаю геокодеру частями. Пример кода:

```
            var fullLength = myArray.length;          
        //здесь режется большой массив 
        var i, j, chunk = 20;
        if (fullLength <= chunk) {
            myGeocode(myArray);
        } else {
            for (i = 0, j = fullLength; i < j; i += chunk) {
                temparray = myArray.slice(i, i + chunk);
                splitArrCount = splitArrCount + 1;
                myGeocode(temparray);
            };
        };
function myGeocode(arr) {

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var addr = arr[i].Город + " " + arr[i].Улица + " " + arr[i].Дом;
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(addr, {results: 1});        
    crtGeocode(myGeocoder, i);
};


function crtGeocode(myGeocoder, i) {  
    setTimeout(
    myGeocoder.then(
        function (res) {
            var strJSON;
            if (res.geoObjects.get(0)) {

                strJSON = {
                    "Область": arr[i].Область,
                    "Город": arr[i].Город,
                    "Улица": arr[i].Улица,
                    "Дом": arr[i].Дом,
                    "LAT": res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry._coordinates[0],
                    "LNG": res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry._coordinates[1]
                };
                tmpJSON.push(strJSON);
            } else {
                var strErr = {
                    "Область": arr[i].Область,
                    "Город": arr[i].Город,
                    "Улица": arr[i].Улица,
                    "Дом": arr[i].Дом,

                };
                errArr.push(strErr);
            };
        })
        .fail(function (err) {              
            console.log('error', err);
            throw err;
        }), 50000);
};
};
```

Comment: А еще периодически 502 ошибка появляется.

Comment: В настройках пхп есть max_execution_time(или похожее, пишу по памяти) Увеличте эту устновку, должно помочь.

Comment: Это если на вашем сервере пхп не хватает времени загрузить данные.

Comment: Мне кажется разбиение на мелкие массивы не особо помогает. Т.к. используется promise, то адреса просто копятся в очереди и на сервер отправляются всей кучей. Как победить такое поведение?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился с помощью 
[HTTP-геокодера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/)